# Defining magento template path

Tags: magento

I am programmatically loading a block inside **Magento admin controller** like this

```
`$block = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('core/text')->setText('<script type="text/javascript" ></script>');`
```

Now, instead of setText, I would like to use setTemplate method. I have created a temlplate file in this directory design/adminhtml/default/default/product/productcrop.phtml

How should I load it,i.e.,what would be the argument inside setTemplate method?

I tried this way: ->setTemplate('adminhtml/product_productcrop.phtml'). But it doesn't seems to be working.

The whole controller code is:

```
<?php 
class Homeliv_Leadsadmin_Adminhtml_ProductController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action {
    public function indexAction() {
        $this->loadLayout()->_setActiveMenu('leadsadmin/product');
        $this->_addContent($this->getLayout()->createBlock('leadsadmin/adminhtml_product'));
        $this->renderLayout();
    }

    public function editAction() {

        $product_id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
        $full_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_id);
        $productMediaConfig = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_media_config');
        //$baseImageUrl = $productMediaConfig->getMediaUrl($full_product->getImage());
        //$thumbImageUrl = $productMediaConfig->getMediaUrl($full_product->getThumbnail());
        $smallImage = $productMediaConfig->getMediaUrl($full_product->getSmallImage());


        $this->loadLayout();
        //$this->_title($this->__("Product"));   
       /* $block = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('core/text')->setText('<script type="text/javascript" src="'.Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_WEB).'media/leadsadmin/product_crop.js'.'"></script>');
        $this->_addJs($block);

        $this->_addLeft($this->getLayout()
        ->createBlock('core/text')
         ->setText('<h1>Image</h1><img src="'.$smallImage.'"/>'));



        $block = $this->getLayout()
        ->createBlock('core/text')
        ->setText('<h1>Main Block</h1>');           
        $this->_addContent($block);*/


        $block = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('core/template')-> setTemplate('product/productcrop.phtml')->toHtml();
        $this->_addContent($block);

        //$this->getLayout()->createBlock('leadsadmin/adminhtml_product')->setTemplate('product/productcrop.phtml')->toHtml();
        //$this->getLayout()->createBlock('core/text')->setText('<div>ssxsxsx</div>');
        $this->renderLayout();

        //var_dump(Mage::getSingleton('core/layout')->getUpdate()->getHandles());
        //die();

        //$this->loadLayout()->_setActiveMenu('leadsadmin/product');
        //$this->_addContent($this->getLayout()->createBlock('leadsadmin/adminhtml_product'));
        //$this->renderLayout();
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for the template you have. you template path will be to set template `product/productcrop.phtml`

```
 $block = $this->getLayout()
    ->createBlock('core/template')
    ->setTemplate('product/productcrop.phtml');

$this->getLayout()->getBlock('content')->append($block);
```

Comment: i used this to add block: $this->_addContent($block); It throws error: Recoverable Error: Argument 1 passed to Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action::_addContent() must be an instance of Mage_Core_Block_Abstract

Comment: can you explain what you trying to achieve so i can help.

Comment: I added the controller code in the question. I just want to load my phtml file programatically